# NullPointerException on file.getAbsolutePath() but file.exists() returns true

Tags: java, xml, file, xpath, nullpointerexception

I'm writing an application where I'm using XPath to parse an xml file. Before i call DocumentBuilder's parse method, I create a File from the filename, and check if the file exists. This check returns true, but when i try to parse the file I get a nullpointerexception with this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.normalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getUserPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getAbsolutePath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getAbsoluteFile(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at FileHandler.parseFile(OriginatorHandler.java:112)
    at Main.main(Main.java:58)
```

The file is in the same folder as I run the .jar application, and it has the right content. Here is my code:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> parseFile(String fileName) {

    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't find file [" + fileName + "]");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    Document document = null;

    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        //This is where the exception is thrown 
        document = builder.parse(file);

        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

        return getCaGroups(document, xPath);

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What can this error come frome? The file exists, it isn't null and is in the folder where I run the .jar file. What else could cause this problem?

Comment: What is the value of `fileName`?

Comment: Possibly just a side note, but you should use `file.isFile()` instead of `file.exists()`. `exists()` will return true for folders.

Comment: The value of fileName is the name of the file, and fileName equals file.getName(). Thank you for the tip, I changed it to file.isFile(), but still get the same stacktrace.

Comment: The stacktrace shows that `parseFile()` calls `getAbsolutePath()`, but the code shown does *not* have any call to `getAbsolutePath()`, so **that is not the code that is failing**. Please recompile your code and try again.

Comment: I repeat. What is the value of `fileName`? I do *not* need to be told that 'it is the name of the file'. I am asking you *what* is the name of the file. Also what is the real code? Because this isn't it. It doesn't call the method that is throwing the exception.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, but I by mistake put in the wrong stacktrace from where I tried to call file.getAbsolutePath() directly just for testing. I have added the correct stacktrace now.

Comment: File name is 2016-04-12_info.xml.

Comment: pass the absaluteFilePath and change the xml file content to some simple parsable xml content. I just checked the same parseFile class and it parsed the xml without any issue (with absolute file path).

Answer (score -1):

Please put the Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

100 % you are successfully in you job.

Comment: How is it related to `android` ?